# Adding HTML content to a flash website

Tags: html, css, flash, facebook-like, css-float

I have a flash website in which I was trying to make some modifications. I am attempting to add the facebook social plugin *** a layer over my flash page. I am not very experienced in coding and web design so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently, the facebook plugin is displayed briefly before the flash starts loading then it disappears after the page is loaded. What do I need to do for the plugin to display on the webpage in order to look like it is part of the flash site?

I had some help from one of the forum moderators but he suggested that I should try and get some new eyes to take a look at the page. Can anyone help me out? Please?

The page is http://www.djjigs.com

The green background of the facebook plugin and position is just temp for testing purposes until I can get this page to display properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can not add facebook social plugins to a flash movie. But you can do your own plugin with facebook graph api.

and maybe you can add a div over flash object on your page.